# Node Restful returning array of JSON

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, rest

I recently started using Node-Restful and I am seeing that an array is being returned when I hit a `GET` request.

What I want

`{"_id":"56","name":"something"}`

What I am getting

`[{"_id":"56","name":"something"}]`

How does Node-restful handle `GET` requests? And how do I override this? Is there anyway that Node-restful takes care of this?

Comment: are you developing the server side? in these case you have to be able to return a single JSON instead of an array

Comment: So where's the code you're using?

Comment: It is on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think that default implementation for get request is to return an array of requested data. if you want just one of them, you should send id of object in database.

GET /resources        -> returns array of objects in database

GET /resources/:id    -> returns just one object with given id